# Rest philosophy for updating and getting records

Tags: api, rest, client-server

In my app I'm displaying **Race** objects that essentially have three states: **pending**, **inProgress** and **completed**. I want to display all **Races** that are currently **pending** or **inProgress**, but not the ones that are **completed**. To do this, I want to create a RESTful API for getting these resources from my server, but I'm not sure what the best (i.e. most RESTful) approach would be.

The issue is that when someone opens or refreshes the app, I need to two things:

1. Perform a GET on all the **Races** that are currently displayed in the client to update their status.
2. GET all of the new **pending** or **inProgress Races** that have been created since the client last updated

I've come up with a few different solutions, though I don't know which, if any, would be best:

1. Simply delete the old **Race** records on the client and always GET all new records
2. Perform 2 separate GET operations, the first which updates all the old records, and the second where I GET all the new **pending** / **inProgress Races**
3. Perform a single GET operation where I specify the **created** date of the last client record, and GET all records that are newer.

To me, this seems like a pretty common scenario but I haven't been able to find a specific answer to this type of problem. I'd like to see what SO thinks :)

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

> Simply delete the old Race records on the client and always GET all new records

This is probably the easiest solution. However you shouldn't do that if you need a very smooth update on your client (for games, data visualization, etc.).

> Perform 2 separate GET operations (...) / Perform a single GET operation where I specify the created date of the last client record, and GET all records that are newer.

I would definitely do it with a single operation. Better than an update timestamp (timestamp operations are costly, and several operations could happen at the same time), I would use a sequence number. [This is the way CouchDB handles "changes"](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/notifications.html). 
Moreover, as you will see in the documentation, this solution can then be upgraded for asynchronous notifications (if you need so).